# Differentiate between AltGr and Ctrl+Alt

Tags: eclipse, windows

I am using a Hungarian keyboard layout when working with Eclipse, and it is quite a pain to work with some keyboard hotkeys, as Eclipse handles <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>AltGr</kbd> as the same.

As a workaround, I have to unbind all shortcuts, which map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+something, if I want to use <kbd>AltGr</kbd> with that. It is quite irratating, because I really need <kbd>|</kbd>, <kbd><</kbd>, <kbd>></kbd>, <kbd>#</kbd>, <kbd>&</kbd>, <kbd>@</kbd>, <kbd>{</kbd>, and <kbd>}</kbd> while coding :)

Is there a way to make Eclipse distinguish between these keys?

Edit: This looks like a Windows specific "feature", it would be nice to override this though.

Comment: It concerns also other nationalities. For some unfortunate and hardly comprehensible reason <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is treated by Eclipse as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>... This probably came from unawareness of *7-bit-ANSI-like-keyboard* programmers of extra national characters reached by <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>KEY</kbd> instead of being "dead codes". Damn pitty.

Comment: @Cromax It is a Windows "feature". The "solution" is warning authors to fix their crappy plugins, which use Alt in their shortcuts - I am looking at you Oracle.

Answer (score 1):

How about you change the keyboard settings to work as an english keyboard while you code and then set it up back to Hungarian when you have finished (if the problem is the Hungarian configuration ofc...)? Or... you could always install a program and set your own shortcuts to be do/behave like you want, with something like: https://autohotkey.com/ for example (there are plenty of other opensource keyboard/macro programs if that one doesn't satisfy you), set everything there and get rid of the eclipse shortcuts.

Comment: @meskobalazs Then, I don't think there is much you can do besides what I've suggested.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In Eclipse, you can do the following:

1. Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Keys
2. In the 'filter...' field enter literally this: Ctrl+Alt+X

The list now shows all bindings for this key combination. Take a screenshot or write down the bindings, then **Unbind** all of them, Apply and close.
Now AltGr+X key (= right alt+x) gives # character.

Comment: Upvoted, because this is what I've been doing in the last 7 years, it is just annoying to do this for every single workspace (well, actually I am copying one configured empty worspace, so I don't have to do this very often).